Change error message when wrong login
I'm trying to change the login error message. I went into /etc/pam.d/auth-config to change the file to :
#Authentification
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]   pam_unix.so nullok
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]   pam_sss.so use_first_pass

#Error message
auth    [default=die]                pam_echo.so file=/etc/security/wrong_password_message

#Reject connection
auth    requisite                    pam_deny.so

auth required pam_permit.so
auth    optional                     pam_cap.so

It kind of works, it prints the "wrong_password_message"'s error-message, but then it also prints the default error message (in french : "Désolé, la connexion par mot de passe a échoué. Veuillez recommencer")
I guess that it's the pam_deny.so command which makes that. But I found that it cant be changed ?
Can I do that changes ?
Moreover, I would like to changes all of the error messages in my Ubuntu session (not only the login error message but also the one in the shell, etc...)
Thank you for your answer and sorry for my english, it's not my native language :/
